# a subclassed model can't save using to_json() in tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to save my subclassed `model(tf.keras.Model)` using `model.to_json()`.
However, when I tried to save it, I got this error below.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in to_json(self, **kwargs)
   1296         A JSON string.
   1297     """
-> 1298     model_config = self._updated_config()
   1299     return json.dumps(
   1300         model_config, default=serialization.get_json_type, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in _updated_config(self)
   1274     from tensorflow.python.keras import __version__ as keras_version  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
   1275 
-> 1276     config = self.get_config()
   1277     model_config = {
   1278         'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in get_config(self)
    965   def get_config(self):
    966     if not self._is_graph_network:
--> 967       raise NotImplementedError
    968     return copy.deepcopy(get_network_config(self))
    969 

NotImplementedError:
```

Saving via `checkpointmanager` works very well though, I want to check whether the inference using `model_from_json` is faster than `model.load_weights` or not.

`python = 3.6,
tensorflow = 2.2`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't but if you see the error, at the last line, it states that the method you are trying to use is not implemented. 
Checking the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#custom_objects) you can see that the `.to_json()` method is not supported for the sub-classed models because they are essentially python bytecode. You can try to serialize them but it is difficult, unsafe and has several drawbacks. 
I would recommend to use the Functional API.